# how to sum rows based on a unique identifier

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (3million+ rows,14 cols) showing daily hourly temperatures over a year for 346 unique latitudes and longitudes

```
JULDAY, D0cm, D2.5cm, ....
1       .84   .76
1       .83   .78
2       .20   .23
2       .19   .19
...
365     .026  .076
365     .025  .053
```

JULDAY is 365 days divided into 24 hrs (e.g. 1 hr per row, 24 rows per day) and a corresponing temperature value according to depth

I think there should be a simple solution here but cannot seem to figure it out.

basically I want to sum the 24 values per day in `D0cm` and `D2.5` etc. for all 365 unique values in JULDAY 
this should give me 365 values i.e. the sum of each days 24 hr values

Is it a case of creating a for loop?
I am sure someone out there can point me in the right direction

Sorry if I am not explaining myself well but I am very tired...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(JULDAY) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum = sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by = JULDAY]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I had been using                                                     `library(dplyr)soiltemps %>%
       group_by(JULDAY) %>%
      summarise_each(SumD0cm = sum(D0cm), SumD2.5cm = sum(D2.5cm)),`but the second data.table works much better. New it was a simple answer